# How to improve Naive Bayes?

Tags: probability, classification, naive-bayes

I am solving a problem that address this question "What are the Actions that lead to high or low score?"

I have the following Data that consist of text and score , I want to derive the words or Actions from text that lead to high/low score

I have huge data , and text length can be a paragraph, sample data like below

```
+----------------------+-------+
|         Text         | Score |
+----------------------+-------+
| Support Team Goal    |    90 |
| Generate Lead        |    80 |
| Contact 30 customers |    30 |
| Support Team Goal    |    30 |
+----------------------+-------+
```

### Approach followed:

I followed Naive Bayes way.

1. First I classified my Data into High (score(75 and above)) and Low (score below 75)
2. I converted the High to Term Document Matrix and the Low as well
3. **I  found words appearing only in low** and judge they lead to low score (include word if frequency greater than 7 lets say)
4. **I found words appearing only in high** and judge they lead to high score
   (include word if frequency greater than 7 lets say in high)
5. **I found probability of common words**, For words appearing in both high or low, I calculated the probability of the word occurrence to happen in low/high
   (include word if probability greater than 75%)

Note: I worked with bigrams. Not sure if this is the right approach to analyze my problem, or there are better techniques. Please advise